# Is there a way to pull user information like user's photo, name, and location from whoever liked your business page on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, interface

Is there a way to pull user information like user's photo, name, and location from whoever liked your business page on facebook?

I'm trying to pull the last 13 users who have liked or who have access to

Answer (score 1):

No, this is only possible if you have also auth'd those users for an app and [requested relevant permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/). This is the only way you can do so.

[Facebook Insights](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/insights/) will provide you with high-level, anonymous demographic information, but nothing specific.